# Decoding utf-8 different language characters in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, encoding, utf-8

I have the following string:

```
"ë \u0088ì \u0084ë\u0093\u009C ì\u0098¤ë¸\u008C ê°\u0093(ë \u0088ì\u0098¤ê°\u0093)"
```

and I want the following output:

```
"레전드 오브 갓(레오갓)"
```

I can do this using javascript, using the following tool

https://mothereff.in/utf-8

If you paste in

```
ë \u0088ì \u0084ë\u0093\u009C ì\u0098¤ë¸\u008C ê°\u0093(ë \u0088ì\u0098¤ê°\u0093)
```

In the "utf-8 encoded" box, you will get the following.

```
"레전드 오브 갓(레오갓)"
```

My question is how do I do this in ruby?

I have tried the following in ruby to no luck.

```
.encode('utf-8')

.force_encoding("utf-8")
```

Thanks!

UPDATE:

It seems like the string I have pasted doesn't work, that's due to some parsing happening when I paste it. 
On the other hand I found the solution.

```
.encode('iso-8859-1')
```

Comment: I don't get the same results you do at mothereff.in, I just get an "invalid input" error. I also can't figure out what encoding your original string is in. Where is that input string coming from and why do you think it matches your desired Korean output?

Comment: `str.encode('iso-8859-1').force_encoding('utf-8')` should do the trick

Comment: @muistooshort SO sanitizes certain characters, you have to copy it from the [edit view](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/29975022/edit).